# Quotes utf 8 not rendering on html

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, mysqli

I'm reading others references on stackoverflow

for add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` under head
[image]

but as you can see on frontend the still not converting to quotes
[image]

but on my db there already converting to quotes
[image]

this my db collection
[image]

I'm using apache server and [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/)  and for editor I'm using [tinymce package for laravel nova](https://github.com/emilianotisato/nova-tinymce/)

when I inspect the element the reults is like this
[image]

`<p>The golden rule when it comes to SEO is that &acirc;&#128;&#156;if it&acirc;&#128;&#153;s good for the user, it&acirc;&#128;&#153;s good for Google.&acirc;&#128;&#157;&nbsp;</p>`

is there something wrong I missed?

Comment: That is likely a copy/paste from something like Microsoft Word.  Smart quotes catch you every time.  There is a paid add on for TinyMCE that handles this.

Comment: yeah but I think the packages didn't support with tinymce pro, I've update my question with add  the results of my inspect element

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored